# The Platinum Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

With the new style that was added to [certain badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/40/c?user_id=22656) (to make them stand out compared to a [normal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer)).

I think we **need** to call these badges platinum (`<apple-marketing>` Read that word again. Amazing. Say that word. This will change your life. Say it again. Now tell me you don't love this idea `</apple-marketing>`)

I'm not sure you even have to put this new badge in the title (user) bar, but they should *at least* be called platinum badges.

Comment: You're a couple of hours late for a Friday-afternoon question, by my watch.

Comment: @mmyers: Yeah but the thing is I'm serious. I know it's sad to see a user with 6K rep on the mother-site asking for such a newbie thing. :(

Comment: Oh. In that case, I'll refer you to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges (which I just snagged from the related list). If that's not relevant, then that probably means it's time for me to get some sleep.

Comment: @mmyers: I saw that too and was hoping the powers that be hadn't already `status-declined` it. Luckily it is **totally** irrelevant.

Comment: "I don't love this idea" (Apple marketing doesn't work well on me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Comment: No, Apple marketing will not change my life, and I loathe the idea. I wish I could downvote this question more than once.

Comment: @mmyers that one is asking for a new level of badge, above gold; this one is asking for the term "platinum badges" to be applied to what we're currently calling "tag badges"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a: that style is for [*tag* badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags); so if you need a name, "tag badges" seems to suffice

b: they already come in different levels, for example [silver](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/151/android) and [gold](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/178/android) - platinum would *presumably* be a new *level* - and no new level has been introduced

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to call them "platinum badges" when the little dot to the left is going to be silver or gold. I'm not sure why anyone thinks the site needs platinum badges - some of the gold ones are hard enough to get as it is.

Answer (score 3):

On my PS3, you get a Platinum trophy for getting every other trophy. The number of Platinum trophies therefore say "this player has pwned # games". A Platinum badge on SO would presumably mean that they have got all other (non-tag) badges, possibly excluding the Precog and Beta.

Comment: Which of course is not possible... :)

Comment: @Mysticial - Excluding precognitive it would be theoretically possible wouldn't it? (albeit extremely unlikely)

Comment: @MartinSmith It becomes a slippery slope. As there are two badges (Tenacious and Unsung Hero) that are practically impossible for many users to get. And for that matter, Tumbleweed is also almost impossible for most of the high-profile users.

Comment: Agree in practice I'd be surprised if it happened. And beta would rule out a whole swathe of people too.

Comment: @Mysticial over 11K with Tenacious and over 3K users with [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge.. that's hardly "impossible". Same for Tumbleweed - just post a lame question on purpose and let it get buried, can't be easier than that. More rep does not mean more views, unless you are Jon Skeet. Only the [Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta) and [Precognitive](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) badges are indeed impossible for mature sites, other than that there's no reason why user can't get all badges.

Comment: +1 from me, if such a thing will ever be introduced then the criteria to have all other badges (or at least all gold non tag badges) is just fine.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd While there may be 3K users that have them, there are many times more than that who have far too many upvoted accepted answers. Are you really trying to encourage people to intentionally post bad answers that don't get votes?

Comment: @Mysticial I agree it's too late for existing users, but it's not too late for new users. As for "encourage people to intentionally post bad answers that don't get votes" no, not at all. But even good answers on unpopular tags on questions having low views won't get upvotes for long time, if at all.