# Should there be any cross-Stack Exchange-site badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-site badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57838/cross-site-badges)

I've noticed that a number of users have made significant contributions across a wide spectrum of Stack Exchange sites. Are there/should there be any badges to recognize generalists at this meta-level?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57838/cross-site-badges