# A new, harder type of badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

I am proposing that there be a new type of badge: Sapphire. The description could read something like this

> Sapphire badges are for the insanely dedicated users of the Stack Exchange. These are near impossible to receive.

You would know that if you saw one of these on a person's profile, they mean business. This would also give those users that seem to have every badge a new chance to prove themselves.

---

Here is a possible list of badges. Under the "New" category, I put down badges that aren't similar to any previous badges

### Question Badges

- ***Need a Name*** - Question favorited by 300 users
- **Remarkable Question** - Question score of 300 or more
- **Rock Star Question** - Asked a question with 30,000 views

#### New

- **Confused** - Be on the top 10 question list of a tag for 1 year

---

### Answer Badges

- **Remarkable Answer** - Answer score of 300 or more
- **Merry go Round** - Provided answer of +30 score to a question of -7 score
- **Underdog** - Zero score accepted answers: more than 50 and 50% of total

#### New

- **Clean Sweep** - 90% Accepted Answer ratio for a month, with at least 50 Answers
- **Know it all** - Be on the top 10 answer list of a tag for 1 year

---

### Tag Badges

- **Sapphire Badge** Total score of 3000 in at least 400 non-community wiki answers.

---

### Moderation Badges

- **Bailiff** - Completed at least 3,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type
- **Master** - Raised 1000 helpful flags
- **Clean Freak** - 12,000 edits (number so high to accommodate for tiny 1 letter changes)
- **Constituent** - Voted on 1800 posts and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

---

### Other

- ***Need a Name*** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 3000 unique IP addresses
- **Dedicated** - Gained 200 rep on 300 days

#### New

- **Supernatural** - Gained 300 rep on one day
- **Ungodly** - Gained 300 rep on 10 days
- **Hacker** - Responsibly disclosed a security flaw in Stack Exchange
- **Lawmaker** - *Had been* a moderator

**Note 1**: The badge names are just an example, along with the requirements. I just wrote it up quick to give an example.

**Note 2**: There is no correlation to the number 3. It is just a random number.

---

It has been brought up that [Platinum Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges) is quite similar. However it is

1. Quite old
2. A discussion question
3. Not specific

However these reasons alone aren't enough to prevent duplicate closing. This question was referring to rewarding people with new badges for something they don't really have control over, such as views and upvotes. Many of these new badges require a lot of work from the person hoping to achieve them.

---

It has been brought up that these requirements would be near impossible for all sites besides stack overflow. These aren't supposed to be too easy. Even though there is the joy of knowing you helped someone, it also adds to your reliability as an answerer. A solution would be to make them harder to obtain on Stack Overflow, because the community is so big. None of the sites will ever be as big as SO, so I think that is a valid solution.

Comment: How about 1500 helpful flags?

Comment: In response to #3, just show it to the left of the gold badge. Simple.

Comment: @CodyGuldner: Providing a list of examples doesn't make this different enough to warrant a separate question.

Comment: @Cody [Are you sure?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Platinum)

Comment: @Cody The original question shows up as the first result in your search, and you are still sure that the search engine sucks? You proposed a harder type of badge called Platinum in your question. That is the keyword.

Comment: @CodyGuldner: And? That's not a magical indicator that automatically makes it not-a-duplicate. The core question behind your feature is if the site should have platinum badges, and the duplicate question has two top-voted answers from SE devs which express clear disinterest in the feature.

Comment: While I agree that this is *technically* a duplicate, the other question is almost 4 years old and I feel weird shutting down a new, more specific proposal as a duplicate of it. So I'm reopening this because you are asking for specific badges to be implemented. However, it wouldn't hurt to edit your question to make the distinction from the old discussion more clear. You might also want to address what (if anything) changed since 2009, since that discussion did end rather unfavourably for what you're proposing here.

Comment: @Undo: You monster.

Comment: All of them need to be much harder to attain.

Comment: Implement this, award me my flag badge and then unimplement it :D

Comment: I don't think most of these are that difficult for SO and most of them are completely impossible for the rest of the network. Most of the question and answer badges require the question to be reddit'ed. Apart from the top 10 lists. I have 15k rep on SO would get a few "sapphire" badges for answering and all bar one of the moderation badges... I imagine there are a fair few people who would do far better than me on this...

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi These are example numbers. Just to show what it would be like

Comment: "[Constituent](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)" badge name is already taken: "Voted for a candidate in the final phase of an election..."

Comment: Giving this a -1. In the last months I went for some reviewing badges and spent a remarkable amount of my time during the day reviewing posts. New badges (especially those you can get by sheer hard work) would encourage me to continue this behavior, whether that is reviewing, flagging or whatever. So for means of self-protection and prevention of addiction: Leave the badges as they are...

Answer (score 20):

The purpose of badges it to reward behavior that is desirable, to be something to strive for that at the same time causes good actions and/or learning the system along the way.

What purpose would platinum badges serve?  They're almost all exclusive to Stack Overflow by sheer counts, and most serve only to reward the very, *very* top users.  As a developer: we have enough trouble with Skeet's badge count overflowing the user card space, adding a badge level isn't going to help.

On pretty much every site besides Stack Overflow, they would never be awarded - making the problem of the gold badge counts (many of which are already unattainable in small communities) even worse.

The other badges, being in the top `n` users for `x` time period would be fine as gold badges...*if* they were technically possible.  Unfortunately, they aren't without a significant addition to or data logging and a *hugely* expensive query to check that data (users x badges is a ***huge*** dataset).

Keep in mind I'm saying this as being one of the very few users that would earn any of these.

Oh yeah, one more thing...who said the Hacker badge doesn't already exist?

Comment: I thought the Hacker badge was a job offer from the StackOverflow team....

Comment: Then maybe it is time to lower badge requirements for smaller sites

Comment: @CodyGuldner What happens when the site gets larger?  They are consistent for a reason, otherwise the awarding of them is unfair.

Comment: Well these badges are meant to reward only the most dedicated. It gives them something to shoot for!

Comment: @CodyGuldner I have over 200,000 rep on Stack Overflow and I don't see these are something to shoot for.  The most dedicated are already dedicated, typically because they like helping others...do we need to pin more medals to their chest?

Comment: nice rep, by the way

Answer (score 3):

May I make an alternative suggestion?  Informally implement challenge badges yourself on a site’s meta.  You don’t need Stack Exchange to implement this, so it won’t require going through the long process towards implementation: you can do it today.

Make a meta post and set a challenge for the site.  Whoever wins, you give them a challenge badge (perhaps some nice image; maybe even add the winner’s name to the image to immortalize the win).

One constructive criticism: challenges where it’s “do something X times” are fairly unexciting, and even moreso when there’s already a challenge “do that thing X/3 times”.  You’re more likely to get participation with more imaginative quests.

E.g.:

- The “Augean Stable” badge for whoever makes a long-term dysfunctional tag useful again.
- On some language sites, there’s “translation golf” where the goal is to translate some fixed snippet succinctly yet faithfully.

These imaginative challenges are fun! But harder to concoct.