# Millionaire badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges

How about a millionaire badge?

I got this idea after reading another post about SO recontinuing swag, where one of the answers asked what swag, if any, users would get when they reach one million reputation. Because this is such a major milestone, I am proposing that there is a gold badge to mark when members of SO or another site reach 1 million or 1000k points. (This would also be given to existing users like Jon Skeet who already have reached the 1 million mark.) Please tell me what you think of this idea, and whether or not it is a good idea.

Comment: impossible! useless and can only be achieved by jon skeet! and it might be used for bragging rights!!

Comment: @Ollie This is true, but thinking into the future, more people will eventually reach 1 million, as well as on other sites.

Comment: @Kermit You're right, but that future is a long way away.  Even Shog9 only has 413K and he's been here for quite a while.

Comment: we would need to stay until 2077 to get 1M rep,  and i dont think such badge is any help. when you see a user with 1M rep your eyes pop out, and there is no need to make an additional badge to bring that fact more attention.

Comment: @mindstormsboi A few other users other than Jon Skeet got 1000k, but only a few

Comment: @blockofdiamond yes. only a few. and some communities here are not so active i.e. bricks, so it will be hard to get 1m rep on such sites. we can disallow the badge on those sites, but so far the badges we have aren't really site-specific so if we can't get the badge on some sites then thats just obvious proof it's a bad badge, like the deprecated tumbleweed badge.

Comment: The answers to [Platinum Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges) also address this question.

Answer (score 6):

On one hand, I like the idea of having such a badge, but on the other, it would be work to create a badge for achieving a very lofty goal that only four users currently have, and that's only on Stack Overflow.  Almost no one out of the several million on Stack Exchange would earn it; it just isn't worth it.  The reward those few get is usually a "Congratulations on reaching 1 million rep!!!" post, which I would value far more than a badge.

Comment: The logic for this is so simple it can hardly be much work to implement such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the point given by Ollie, which I contest, btw, I also feel it's a bit condescending. If you take a look at the Stack Overflow profile of [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) you can see that he currently owns 782 gold badges.

[image]

Your first gold badge may feel special, but your 783rd badge certainly has lost most of its appeal by the sheer number of badges it is accompanied by.

#### Such a special occasion (reaching 1M reputation) should be celebrated bigger than a mere gold badge!